# Facebook isn't recognizing development key hash

Tags: android, facebook

I have tried all the other solutions i could find. I have tried deleting the debug.keystore, generating a new development keyhash, no matter what i get the alert saying unrecognized keyhash when clicking the facebook login button when running my app. The key hash that it tells me is unrecognized is definitely saved in my facebook app settings. Why isn't facebook recognizing this key hash, even though it is definitely in the FB app settings?

I have also tried printing the key hash both programmatically and in terminal, both of which were identical giving me this:

[image]

and the facebook app settings match perfectly:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending the correct ID to identify yourself along with the key hash though? And could there be any intermediary changes being made this data before it is sent?

Your best bet would be to attach a debugger exactly before the request is being sent to ensure all values are populated correctly.

EDIT:
Try this solution:
[Android Facebook Key Hash Stopped Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734701/android-facebook-key-hash-stopped-working)

Comment: Yes, the correct id is being sent, it was working yesterday, it just stopped today.

Comment: Yea, sorry tried that already, and just tried it again, just gives me the same key hash that facebook already has